# How to get particular record from a group in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following df

```
pid name plan type...
1   v    a    10
1   s    a    20
1   v    b    10
2   s    c    20
2   v    c    10
3   s    a    10
3   v    a    20...
```

and another df2, which has the id's from the first df and the position of records to be taken from df

```
pid  position
1    1
2    2
3    2
```

So this means that for pid 1, 1 record has to be selected, for pid 2, 2nd, for pid 3, 2nd and so on...

So my output should be like

```
pid name plan type...
1   v    a    10
2   v    c    20
3   v    a    20...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do a `join` and then `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2) %>%
       group_by(pid) %>%
       filter(row_number() == position) %>%
       select(-position)
```